# Gradle distribution plugin: conditionally copy assets

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm packaging my java application using Gradle's Distribution plugin. I wanted to make 2 distributions, one which doesn't include a JRE and another one that bundles a JRE with the app.
I've set up a `copyJre` task and wanted to only make Distributions plugin include a folder (jre-8 in the example below) only when `copyJre` task is in the tasks graph. Here's my attempt which doesn't work.

```
distributions {
  main {
    contents {

      from('/') {
        include 'tools/**'
      }      

      // my attempt to conditionally copy
      // jre-8 directory only when tasks graph contains
      // a task named 'copyJre' 
      if (tasks.findByName('copyJre') != null) {
        from('../../jre-dist/') {
          include 'jre-8/**'
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

There probably should be a better approach in general. This looks like kludges.

Answer (score 0):

From a Gradle perspective, you are better expressing what you need the other way around:

- Create a different distribution that will include the JRE, possibly extracting the common part of the copy spec.
- And if you really only want a single output, make it replace the default distribution after building it.